# Video Tutorial for Hadoop

Tags: nosql, hadoop

have anybody got any link(s) to video tutorial of **starting hadoop**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There a couple of nice videos from Cloudera at

http://www.cloudera.com/resources/?type=Training

Look at the "Cluster Computing and MapReduce Lecture" series in YouTube

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjPBkvYh-ss

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vD6PUdf3Js

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Eib_H_zCEY

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZDybXl212Q

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT-piFBP4fE

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://vimeo.com/8615628) is a video of how to install Arch Linux, and then install Hadoop on top of that.