# Hadoop Hello World Example And Introduction

Tags: hadoop

I've been hearing a lot about Apache Hadoop as an awesome way to do processing intensive taks. Looking for a really basic introduction to Hadoop. Like the `helloworld` equivalent, and then maybe an example use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WordCount example code is so simple that anyone new can understand it.It is there

[https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example:+WordCount+v2.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3a+WordCount+v2.0)

Just compile it with adding all of the haddop Api ex: hadoop-core.jar 
Create a .jar file by netbin and be amazed when it runs with hadoop in cmd.

If you  want another one,I have made a sudo indexer ...like

```
Cow 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt
Cat 1.txt

etc.
```

Just ask me,I will give you the code which is so simple.But I recommend you should run this example first.

Now i thought you have completed the previous task , so here is the link to use >>
http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2011/11/hadoop-simple-indexer-in-map-reduce.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: That link has 404'd, and since it seems to be one of the top results it would be good to put an updated link I think.

Comment: I have updated the link and plus you for reminder ;)

Answer (score 4):

Before jumping into Hadoop, knowledge of MapReduce is required (Hadoop is based on MapReduce). Here are some nice [videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053837/video-tutorial-for-hadoop/7054592#7054592) on MapReduce. Also check Google's [Paper](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) on MapReduce.

Also, if you are really interested in Hadoop, the [Hadoop : The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) is a must to have book.