# Exploring Hadoop code

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, hadoop-plugins

I wanted to know about Hadoop more than a black box. I wanted to explore the Hadoop code itself. How can I download the bundle not from the trunk and where should I start from? Any help would be really helpful
Thanks
Shujaat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadoop code is in [SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/) and in Git also. Setup the Hadoop projects in Eclipse and start exploring the code. Currently [0.23](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.23/), [0.22](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.22/) and [0.20.205](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-205/) branches is all where the active development is happening. [HowToContribte](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute/) is a nice start if you want to know more about the code. Learn what is [MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053837/video-tutorial-for-hadoop/7054592#7054592), [Hadoop](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) and finally setup Hadoop environment on a [Linux](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) [box](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/). Also, subscribe to the Hadoop mailing list and follow the JIRAs.

Not sure why not [trunk](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/). All the fun stuff happens at trunk.

Answer (score 0):

To explorer hadoop code, make sure whether you are explorer in windows or linux box. If it is for windows, visit http://tech.zhenhua.info/2010/11/svn-subclipse.html

Hadoop requires Ivy, sh on windows.

Praveen, "Not Sure why not trunk", i did not understood the line? i used trunk by following these links http://hadoop.apache.org/common/version_control.html